# Analysing length of a string and adding characters to it

Tags: python, string

As you can clearly see from the program below I am rather new to Python (2.7.5) and I decided to put all of my knowledge.py together to create something fun. However if you read over my program, focusing on lines 87-90 it is obvious that I am having an issue. If you run the program and the strings name1, 2 and 3 are more than or equal to 8 characters in length, I have put an error. I have put this in because if the name is longer than 8 characters it will mess up my table. What do you suggest is the best way to get round this? Also, is there anyway I can optimize/make my code more readable?

```
if len(name1) > 8 or len(name2) > 8 or len(name3) > 8:
    print "error- input too large"
else:
    table()
```

Comment: Could you please repost a minimal working example of the code that you are having issues with, so that we can reproduce the errors on our end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that that problem comes with lines of code like:

```
"""something
"""+ name1 + """    """+ age1 + """ """+ colour1 + """
more"""
```

The solution is to use one of python's string formatting methods.  For example the following reserves ten spaces for each variable:

```
"""something
%10s %10s %10s
more""" % (name1, age1, color1)
```

This will make things line up nicely.  Also, by using `%-10s` in place of `%10s`, you can change the alignment.

Putting this into a more complete example:

```
def table(name1='Ann', name2='Dorothy', name3='JJ', 
                age1=1, age2=104, age3=10, 
                color1='red', color2='green', color3='yellow'):
    print """
%-10s %3s   %-20s
%-10s %3s   %-20s
%-10s %3s   %-20s
%-10s %3s   %-20s
""" % ('Name', 'Age', 'Favourite Colour',
                name1, age1, color1, 
                name2, age2, color2, 
                name3, age3, color3, 
                )

table()
```

The above produces output:

```
$ python table.py 

Name       Age   Favourite Colour    
Ann          1   red                 
Dorothy    104   green               
JJ          10   yellow
```

Variables that take up more than their allotted spaces will still cause an issue but fixing that requires you to decide what you want the table to look like.  Truncating an over-long string is one possibility.